# Three.js Postprocessing outline

Tags: three.js, webgl, post-processing

In this example for Three.js:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_outline.html

outline would only work if clearcolor of the renderer is darker than white.

Because of the way OutlinePass is set up - it computes the contour of the mesh and then blends it onto the texture of the original scene by using AdditiveBlending. So if the background in the original scene is white the contour will not show where there is nothing behind the original object:

[image: Broken outline with white background]

I have been trying to make OulinePass to work for the white background for entire day today, but haven't been successful yet.

Any suggestions/help would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Anton.

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: as a quick test, what happens when you add a huge cube to the scene that contains the whole volume of the scene? (use `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.BackSide})`)

Comment: @gman I want the outline to show regardless whether the background is white or black. I spent the entire day reverse-engineering the OutlinePass and experimented with various ways it can blend an outline onto the existing scene - all to no luck. Every result yielded a scene either not showing all the meshes, showing meshes in wrong colors of showing very faint outline (in case I used SubtractiveBlending instead of AdditiveBlending).

Comment: @Martin Schuhfuß - thank you, I will try, but I assume it will yield the same result as in the image above. as long as the color of the scene is white wherever the outline needs to show because of how OutlinePass is set up it tries to add the color of the outline to the already white color of the scene, and adding any color to white still leaves it white. That's why in the example they used in www.threejs.org they used dark meshes and black background color of the scene...

Comment: Why cant you just change the additive blending into some other kind of blending?

Comment: That is what I did yesterday and I got it working for the example above, but without the edge glowing effect. Once I have the full example worked out I will post a response here and make a suggestion on Three.js GitHub page to improve the example on the site.

Comment: any updates on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the blending option in getOverLayMaterial() solved my problem